# Starting new intent

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

Im trying to start a new intent on clicking an item in a listview but dont know how to get this working.

Here is the code:

```
final ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                  
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Profileviewer.class);  
            startActivity(intent); 
        }
});
```

I get an compiller error on `new Intent(this, Profileviewer.class);`

```
The constructor Intent(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, Class<Profileviewer>) is undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass to the intent the context of the **activity** (by putting `YourActivity.this`), by passing only **this**, you are passing the `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()`..

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                  
        Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, Profileviewer.class);  
        startActivity(intent); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice this works like a charm now, just have to wait 5 more minutes to accept this awnser!

Comment: Instead of using YouActivity.this you can also use getBaseContext(); this is really the reason for having that method afaik.

Comment: and why do we need this? :  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot add a new activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are trying to launch an Intent from a ListView. In your code this means the list view. That's what the error message says. You need to use your package name using any of the below methods.

1. `Intent intent = new Intent({package_name}, Profileviewer.class);`
2. `Intent intent = new Intent(Profileviewer.this, Profileviewer.class);`